# Links have random characters prepended in email

Tags: email

I am using the current link in my email.

```
                    <a href="*|baseUrl|*/verifyEmail?token=*|token|*">*|baseUrl|*/verifyEmail?token=*|token|*</a>
```

This however causes one or two people to get strange links from the email and get not found, usually based on some random email providers. E.g. - if I use a 10 minute mail (10minutemail.com), I get the following:

https://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/www.mywebsite.com/verifyEmail?token=b32fee82da59e7b4085269faca35ec7025122876

Correct link: www.mywebsite.com/verifyEmail?token=b32fee82da59e7b4085269faca35ec7025122876

Assuming this is due to baseUrl? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong when setting up my email link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `http://` or `https://` with your baseUrl. Otherwise the email client may prepend a default base address instead of 'just' the missing protocol, especially if it is a webmail client.